# How to make user-defined function return a value when being interrupted?

Tags: r, loops, exception, return, interrupt

Suppose I have a function like the one below:

```
f <- function(x, y, beta) {
  n <- length(y)
  b_values <- rep(0, n)
  b_values[1] <- beta
  for (i in i:n) {
    b_values[i] <- b_values[i + 1] - 0.5 * g(x, y)
  }
  return(b_values)
}
```

It is something similar to stochastic gradient descend, where I am trying to update the parameter value using the previous one.

Sometimes the code takes too long to run and when I interrupt it by pressing esc in R-studio, nothing is returned. What I want to achieve is to make my function return what it already has if the user terminate the function. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple quick fix would be to print value to console within the `for` loop. 

something like `print(b_values[i])` assuming you want that value

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `on.exit()` will do the job.